# reading a text file, then writing to another text without a user input word

Tags: python

I need help reading through a text file to search for a user input word, then copying data from that text file to another text file without the user input word.

```
def remove(infile, outfile, target):
    for line in infile:
      for word in line.split():
        if word != target:
          outfile.write(word)
        
        
def main():
    outfile = open('outputFile.txt', 'w')
    infile = open('inputFile.txt', 'r')
  
    #Ask user for word they would like to omit from outfile 
    target = input("What word would you like to delete from input file?: ")
    remove(infile, outfile, target)
  
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
  
main()
```

The code above works correctly. It searches the first text file for the user input word and writes to a new file, but it doesn't write out with the proper spacing. It is all on one line and doesn't have any spaces. How do I write to the new file with the same spaces, and \n as the original document?

Comment: Is your question how to add back the spaces you removed?

Comment: @Thornily Sorry, I just updated my question. I'm trying to write with proper indents. Right now it works by write every word except the user input, but it's all on one line with no \n. I'm looking to write with same format as the original document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def remove(infile, outfile, target):
    for line in infile:
      for word in line.split(' '):
        if word != target:
          outfile.write(word+' ')  # You forgot to add the space that was removed while splitting the line.
      outfile.write('\n')  # you also forgot to add the newline

        
        
def main():
    outfile = open('outputFile.txt', 'w')
    infile = open('inputFile.txt', 'r')
  
    #Ask user for word they would like to omit from outfile 
    target = input("What word would you like to delete from input file?: ")
    remove(infile, outfile, target)
  
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
  
main()
```